# Writing Blackberry Applications

Tags: blackberry

How can I write Blackberry applications?

I am on OS X Leopard with VMWare.

Answer (score 13):

I've been developing BlackBerry apps for years - almost as long as the devices have been around - and I'm actually currently using a Macbook pro with VMWare, which works well - if you have the RAM (3 gigs is good) and CPU horsepower.

The BlackBerry developer zone (http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/) is definitely the first place you should go - you'll need to download the BlackBerry JDE (Java development environment - their standalone IDE) or the JDE Plugin for Eclipse.  They come with API Javadocs and the standalone JDE comes with sample apps.  There are also support forums, a knowledgebase, etc.  In both cases the simulator is a Windows app - hence the necessity of using Windows for development.

I write a blog about BlackBerry development called [Thinking Blackberry](http://www.thinkingblackberry.com).  It's very new, and so far I've mostly been exploring specific slightly more advanced topics, but I have a [getting started tutorial for the JDE Plugin for Eclipse](http://www.thinkingblackberry.com/archives/21) that's had some good feedback (I'm a proponent of going the Eclipse route for BB development).  It also provides an overview of the options for BlackBerry development, with pluses and minuses for each.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any personal experience but it looks like Blackberry has a pretty extensive [developer resource area](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/resources/)

Answer (score 2):

They have their own SDK too. Search for it at blackberry.com. The language is Java. I don't know much about it. I have a BlackBerry so it's sad, as a C# developer, that I don't develop apps for the CrackBerry. Should be very straight forward, though.

Answer (score 0):

Blackberry does offer pretty extensive documentation.  They're Developer Zone (http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/) is my prime resource.  Unfortunately the Developer Zone is pretty hard to navigate, so here are some of my favorite links:

- Java apps (http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/)
- Javadoc (http://na.blackberry.com/eng/deliverables/5999/index.html?name=BlackBerry+Java+Development+Environment+-+API+Reference4.7.0&language=English&userType=21&category=BlackBerry+Java+Application+Development&subCategory=BlackBerry+Java+Development+Environment)