# Analyze real time audio while recording in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, audio-recording

I am using the answer from the StackOverflow question "[J2ME/Blackberry - get audio signal amplitude level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497706/j2me-blackberry-get-audio-signal-amplitude-level)" for recording audio. But I am unable to analyse the audio in real time. I can get the byte array after recording is stopped, but I want to graph the data as it is recorded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real time processing in Java is problematic but possible. You could have a look at my [Google Code project](http://code.google.com/p/blackberry-real-time-audio/) which takes audio input, computes an FFT and displays the spectrum on the screen. It isn't fancy, but it does work. I'm sure you can work out how to measure audio amplitude in lieu of the FFT.